# program to reverse a string

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C. I was trying this program to reverse a string. Any help whats wrong with it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *reverse(char *);

void main()
{
    char str[]="kundan";
    int len=strlen(str);
    char *ptr;
    ptr=reverse(str);
    printf("the reversed string is :%s",ptr);
}

char *reverse(str)
{
    char *rtr=str;
    char qtr[10];

    for(int i=len-1;i<=0;i--)
    {
        qtr=rtr+i;
        qtr++;
    }
    return qtr;
}
```

Comment: What sort of troubleshooting have you done?  What are you seeing when you try to compile and/or run it?

Comment: for(int i=len-1; **i>=0** ;i--)

Comment: Also, `qtr` is an array, you can't write `qtr++`.

Comment: dude, atleast tell us what you are getting when you compile and run it. And why do you have to mess with pointers when your whole objective is to reverse a string, just do a strlen and print it backwards

Comment: H2CO3 you say qtr++ is an array it can't be incremented. but qtr= &qtr[0] which makes it a pointer. so why not to incremnet it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this reverseString algorithm work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485585/how-does-this-reversestring-algorithm-work)

Comment: those who say that its low quality question,man i accept i a beginner but what about u guys, u are professional so instead of making this program correct why are u complaining.what do i think of u professionals

Comment: this site is of no help.

Comment: @KundanNegi I'm not saying you should not write `qtr++`, I'm saying it's a compiler error because arrays ain't pointers. You can't increment an array, only a pointer.

Comment: @KundanNegi - If you're still having problems, update your original post with your latest version of code and let me know where you stand (i.e. what sort of problems you're seeing).  Don't just post your code & say "fix this for me", post your code & say what you've done to try to figure out the problem, and where you're stuck & need help.  When you reply, be sure to start your comment with "@phonetagger" so that I know you replied to me.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't respecting variable `scope`. One useful reference about this, [here](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/scope.html).

For example, in `reverse()`, you refer to `len` in the `for` loop. However, `len` is defined in `main`, and therefore isn't available to `reverse()`. *(Does this even compile?)*

The value you're returning from `reverse()` is a pointer to a stack value that is only in scope in that function. While the calling function, `main()`, will end up with a valid pointer, the information that the pointer is referring to has dropped out of scope when `reverse()` returned, and is therefore *volatile*, subject to change. For this simple example, you could return the reversed string by value, rather than by reference. (Send back the array of characters, not a pointer to them.)

Comment: i compiled it and it says that reverse function argument is not correct

Comment: You've forward-declared `reverse` (aka prototype), but then the actual declaration doesn't match it - in fact, it doesn't give a type for the variable. You needed `char *reverse(char *str)`.