# c program using pointers of reverse

Tags: c

Why it's not functioning? compiler says its returning local address. any help how to make it it correct. i saw other reverse string programs but i didn't find any problem in it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *reverse(char *str);

void main()
{
    char str[]="jamesbond";
    int len=strlen(str);
    char *ptr;
    ptr=reverse(str);
    printf("the reversed string is :%s",ptr);
}

char *reverse(char *str)
{ 
    int i,j;
    int len=strlen(str);
    char qtr[len];

    for( i=len-1;i<=0;i--)
    { 
        for( j=0;j<len-1;j++)
            qtr[j]=*(str+i);
    }
    return qtr;
}
```

Comment: You cant return `qtr`, it is not valid after `reverse` exits.

Comment: Please do a minimum of research before asking a question. Searching for the error message in Google will yield a ton of helpful results.

Comment: Also, check [this](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284376&answer=1044841143) please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c

Comment: In short, you are returning garbage. Since you have pointers in C why not make reverse prototype like int reverse(char *instr, char *reversed)

Comment: Note that this question is merely a repost of Kundan's original post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504993/program-to-reverse-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qtr` is a local array, and you're returning a pointer to it.  You can't do that.  You need to allocate dynamic memory and return that:

```
char *qtr = malloc(len + 1);
```

Note that you will need to `free()` this memory sometime.  Alternately, just do the reversal in place:

```
char *start = str;
char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
char tmp;

while (start < end)
{
   tmp = *start;
   *start++ = *end;
   *end-- = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Carl Norum: you want to say that we can return a local address only if its dynamically allocated by using malloc().

Comment: If you allocate it using `malloc` it's not a local address.

Comment: Carl Norum: i did as you said of using malloc.but compiler gives following error   warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]

Comment: You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc()`.  I think you would benefit from reading some beginner tutorials to get up to speed on the basics.

Comment: Carl Norum: ya you are right. i am a beginner. i just enrolled for C a week ago. Can u recommend a nice book for me

Comment: Carl Norum: Now there are no errors but there is no answer. only the printed statement is: the reverse string is me@home$

Comment: Well, your code has other bugs, too.  Try using a debugger to step through and see what's up.  Hint - your nested loops aren't right.

Comment: what debugger can i use for ubuntu linux

Comment: `gdb` is pretty much standard.

Answer (score 0):

returning a stack variable(or array) (here `qtr`) from a function is undefined behavior. It will be overwritten.

Solution is to `malloc()` the array and return that instead, then `free()` it when you're done using it.

Answer (score 0):

qtr is being allocated on the stack. Memory which goes out of scope as soon as your function returns. You could declare qtr as static as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the first for loop must be change to

```
i >= 0



for( i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
  { for( j=0;j<len-1;j++)
    qtr[j]=*(str+i);

   }
```

And since you are not passing the pointer to the resulting array.

It is better to malloc for qtr

```
qtr = malloc(sizeof(strlen(str));
```

Also

```
 int len=strlen(str);
```

in your main() is an unwanted computation.

Answer (score 0):

I fount this pice of code somewhere. Looks legit. And if you don't want to ruinn you input string just deep copy the pointer (memcpy()) and insert it in.

```
char* strrev( char* s)
  {
  char  c;
  char* s0 = s - 1;
  char* s1 = s;

  /* Find the end of the string */
  while (*s1) ++s1;

  /* Reverse it */
  while (s1-- > ++s0)
    {
    c   = *s0;
    *s0 = *s1;
    *s1 =  c;
    }

  return s;
  }
```